# sails.js:mysql connection failed ReferenceError: localMysql is not defined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to connect mysql database to  my sailsjs application

in `config/connections.js`

```
localMysql:{ //arbitrary name
        adapter: 'sails-mysql',
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root'
    }
```

and in `config/models.js`

```
module.exports.models = {
    connection:localMysql

}
```

> But i got the following error `include-all` attempted to
>   `require(/var/www/node/sails-test/config/models.js)`, but an error
>   occurred::  Details:ReferenceError: localMysql is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `string`:

```
module.exports.models = {
    connection: 'localMysql'
};
```

http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-connections

Comment: Let me try your answer

Comment: do you have an answer for thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541025/sails-js-session-undefined-on-page-refresh