# Sails.js session undefined on page refresh

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

In my sails.js application i am setting up session like this

```
    req.session.userId="hello";
    console.log(req.session.userId);
```

after the first request i hide this line  `req.session.userId="hello";`

after that `console.log(req.session.userId)` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough without seeing more of your controller code, but the session property you are setting is only going to be processed into session upon completing the controller action - e.g. returning a view or json.

Try:

```
if(req.session && req.session.userId){
  //This user has an active session already so we have a userid
  sails.log.info(req.session.userId);
else{
  //Must be the first time this action was executed
  req.session.userId = 'hello';
}
res.view('index');
```

where index is the name of your ejs view. If you never return anything then the session property is never set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this was i've tried in my controller on the first page load i've set session with `req.session.userId = 'hello';` and it will accessed  another method in the same controller `concole.log(req.session.userId)` but i got undefind error

Comment: Yes you can't set and get the session property 'userId' within the same action. If you don't return from the controller action, then req.session.userId never gets set. So you need to 1) check for the req.session and req.session.userId 2) if not set, go ahead and set it, if already set then print it to the console 3) complete the request by returning a view or json. Then when you refresh the page the code repeats and it will find the userId from the previous execution of the controller action. Hope that helps.

Comment: One more question when server restarts session is undefined  why its happen??

Comment: Because session data does not persist by default. You can use redis/mongo to provide persistent session storage - writing your session data to a db. In config/session.js - set adapter: 'mongo' then set url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/your-database-name',

Comment: Or if you're using passport and have a logged in user then the session will be available for that user